# How to initiate IF statement if variable is only contained in matrix (matlab)

Tags: matlab, if-statement, matrix

I am looking to achieve something that seems fairly simple, just not sure how to implement ORs in an IF statement:

```
A = [4 6 7; 3 4 7; 8 7 1]
C = 6
if C is in first row of A 
(i.e. if row 1 contains 6, basically -- IF C = 4 or C=6 or C=7)    
    (then do this)
end
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Kelly, you've been on SO a while now. Try to format your (pseudo)code correctly..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So

```
A(1,:) == C
```

is a start.  In your case, it will return a 3 element boolean array where

```
ans(1) = 1 if A(1,1) == C, 0 otherwise
ans(2) = 1 if A(1,2) == C, 0 otherwise
ans(3) = 1 if A(1,3) == C, 0 otherwise
```

From there, you could do something like

```
if( sum(A(1,:) == C) )
# or
if( length(find(A(1,:) == C)) )
```

would work.

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly what I was looking for! And thanks for the concise explanation ... made it easier to understand what is occurring.

Comment: Happy to help!  (there was a small typo on the first line of the third block that I just fixed as well).

Comment: Can this same logic also be used to "retrieve" that column. In the original case -- column [6;4;7]?

Comment: `find` will do that.  It will return the index(es) of any nonzero entries in the matrix you pass to it.  So `find(A(1,:) == C)` will return either `[]` (when C doesn't equal any entries in the first row), `1`,`2` or `3` (when C matches the entry in the first row, first column, second column or third column respectively).  So something like `A(:,find(A(1,:) == C))` should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
   A = [4 6 7; 3 4 7; 8 7 1];
   C = 6;

   rowNum = 1;

   if (sum(A(rowNum,:) == C) ~= 0)
      do something
   end
```